# Grouping rows by fixed integer window that resets above a threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, recursive-query

I am trying to group rows together using a counter of elapsed days from the previous row. These groups would represent a period of 180 elapsed days and no more. If a new row would break this rule (i.e. be >180 days past the first row in the group), it becomes the new first row in a group and a new 180 day starts from it. And to add one more layer, we're also grouping across customers, so .

For example, given the following data:

| elapsedDaysSinceLastRow | customer | rowDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | X | \\\ |
| 90 | X | \\\ |
| 120 | X | \\\ |
| 100 | X | \\\ |
| 100 | X | \\\ |
| 0 | Y | \\\ |
| 10 | Y | \\\ |
| 136 | Y | \\\ |
| 738 | Y | \\\ |
| 40 | Y | \\\ |
| 874 | Y | \\\ |
| 317 | Y | \\\ |
| 285 | Y | \\\ |

We'd want our SQL to generate the following grouping column:

| elapsedDaysSinceLastRow | grouping | customer | rowDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | X | \\\ |
| 90 | 1 | X | \\\ |
| 120 | 2 | X | \\\ |
| 100 | 2 | X | \\\ |
| 100 | 3 | X | \\\ |
| 0 | 1 | Y | \\\ |
| 10 | 1 | Y | \\\ |
| 136 | 1 | Y | \\\ |
| 738 | 2 | Y | \\\ |
| 40 | 2 | Y | \\\ |
| 874 | 3 | Y | \\\ |
| 317 | 4 | Y | \\\ |
| 285 | 5 | Y | \\\ |

So far, we haven't been able to figure out how to do this with windowing functions. It seems like only recursion has worked.

Unfortunately, the recursion is extremely slow and won't work for our use case.

Are there any recommendations for how we could change the structure of our data to support a window-function approach or how we could speed up our recursive query?

Our recursive query is as follows:

```sql
daysOngoing AS (
(
SELECT *
,1 AS firstIn180Days
FROM tblAbove i
WHERE transactionNumber = 1
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT i.*
,CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN d.firstIn180Days = 1 AND (i.elapsedDaysSinceLastRow > 180) THEN 0
WHEN d.firstIn180Days = 0 AND (d.elapsedDaysSinceLastRow + i.elapsedDaysSinceLastRow > 180) THEN 0
WHEN d.firstIn180Days = 1 AND (i.elapsedDaysSinceLastRow < 180) THEN i.elapsedDaysSinceLastRow
WHEN d.firstIn180Days = 0 AND (d.elapsedDaysSinceLastRow + i.elapsedDaysSinceLastRow < 180) THEN d.elapsedDaysSinceLastRow + i.elapsedDaysSinceLastRow
ELSE 0
END) > 0 THEN 0
WHEN d.rowDate = i.rowDate THEN 0
ELSE 1
END AS firstIn180Days
FROM tblAbove i
JOIN daysOngoing d
ON i.journeyId = d.journeyId AND i.transactionNumber = d.transactionNumber + 1
)
)
SELECT elapsedDaysSinceLastRow
,SUM(firstIn180Days) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY customer, rowDate ASC) grouping
,customer
,rowDate
FROM daysOngoing
```

Comment: can you share the output corresponding to the provided input? @PatrickGorman

Comment: Is the data in your question sample data or the expected output? Whichever, your question needs *both*.

Comment: The grouping column is our expected output.  I separated the input data from the output data for reference

Comment: The core issue in this problem is how to determine the frontiers between groups. This is trivial for if rows are processed sequentially (as in Java, C#, etc.) but not for a SQL database that rely on processing data in any order. Now, the recursive CTE can simulate the sequentiality you need, at a high cost. If SQL Sever had pipelined table functions (Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL) it would be trivial to preprocess the data in a function call, but I think this functionality is not implemented.

Comment: Your *row date* column appears to be blank - this is cruicial data as without it there is no such thing as a "last row"

Comment: Another option is to select the data in the appropriate order `ORDER BY customer, rowdate` and then compute the groups in your app logic. With the appropriate index it should be quite fast.

Comment: If there were gaps between grouping values, like `1,1,1,2,4,5,6` (the 3 is missing), would it be fine for you? @PatrickGorman

Comment: You need to simulate dynamic frame partitioning based on a specific condition (sum<180). You won't be able to do this with the window functions `partition by` clause as sql server do not support dynamic frame specification. This does not exclude that a complex workaround may exist though.

Answer (score 1):

The following provides your desired results for the sample data, making the assumption `rowdate` can be used for ordering; does this work for you?

```
with m as (
    select *,
      case when Sum(elapsedDaysSinceLastRow)
          over(partition by customer order by rowdate) % 180 < elapsedDaysSinceLastRow 
        then 1 else 0 
      end rs
    from t
)
select elapsedDaysSinceLastRow, 
  Sum(rs)over(partition by customer order by rowdate) + 1 [grouping], 
  customer, rowdate
from m;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be given us the desired result.  We tried it in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=58c3b7124b196be46ebb90a7481796ac and it did not seem to give us the correct groupings.  Also notice that we updated the example data and check out our comment on lemon's answer

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use the `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` frame specification inside a `SUM` window function over the field `elapsedDaysSinceLastRow` and partitioning on the `customer` field. Once you get the cumulative sum, you can divide by 180 and add 1 to get the increasing value you need.

```
SELECT elapsedDaysSinceLastRow,
       (SUM(elapsedDaysSinceLastRow) OVER(PARTITION BY customer 
                                          ORDER     BY customer
                                          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))/180+1, 
       customer,
       rowDate
FROM tab
```

Quite efficient, though it comes with a drawback (previously pointed in the comments): since we divide by 180, if the difference between one row and the consecutive is bigger than 180 (as it happens for customer 2 on last row), you will get skipped values for this `grouping` calculated field (1>1>1>2>4 instead of 1>1>1>2>3).

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=58c3b7124b196be46ebb90a7481796ac).

Comment: The ```grouping``` count or order does not matter as long as they are distinct for each ```grouping``` within a ```customer```.  The biggest issue we've faced here is that after reaching over 180 days, we want the day count to reset at 0 and all events within 180 days of that event to be included in the next grouping.  Look at the updated example to get a better idea of the specifications